# Get current page's background color in SCSS/SASS/Angular 7

Tags: angular, sass

I'm trying to get, in my SCSS file for a component, or even within the component TypeScript file, the background of the whole page or theme.

I've tried:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

#elementToColor {
    $backgroundColor: $map-get($theme, background-color);

    background-color: $backgroundColor;
}
```

but it doesn't know how to find the theme.

I have not found a way, within the component TS file to find the background color either.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want `background-color` throughout the application?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't know how to find the theme"? If it is an incorrect path why don't you try and fix the path so it is correct?

Comment: @TilakDewangan Yes, that is what I would like, the background-color throughout the application, say CSS's 'body' declaration.

Comment: @Mathyn I have tried the path to my apps main scss file without luck.

Comment: Sorry, I actually want the background color of a mat-drawer-container.  So how can I with SASS get an elements properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of the theme builder function.

For example:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-amber);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$theme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
$bg: map-get(map-get($theme, background), background);

#elementToColor {
    background: #{$bg};
}

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

Comment: This looks promising, but is this in the main SCSS file, or the components SCSS?

Comment: I ask, because I have my main $theme setup in my master mat-theme.scss file.  Do I need to redefine all my primary, accent, and warn?